That darn verb to be!
I teach conversational English in Thailand and have a student who took a practice TOEIC test. The question below was on the test. Can someone here explain to me why “be” is the correct answer and not “is”?
I can only say that I feel a little more comfortable with “be” than with “is”, though I don’t feel a strong rejection of “is”, so I suppose it’s fairly common to say “is” in this sort of sentence.

It is considered strategically vital that our in-flight service ____ up to par.
 A. was 
B. is 
C. be 
D. been

Thanks very much :)

@ohshitgorillas - The subjunctive is practically dead or dying in British and American English.

@MichaelHarvey American English still uses it in formal settings

@ohshitgorillas -I think anyone in the UK born before about 1970 will be familiar with the subjunctive, but many see it as kind of 'prissy' or 'over-correct', especially younger folk.

Thanks a ton to you all for your responses. I've always been very pleased with the sincerity of the answers I get from this forum ... much appreciated. I enjoy reading your more personal stories / tangents too ... they're sometimes amusing :)
Not sure how to just say thanks to everyone, even though I've used the platform several times already. I'm not answering my question, but I'm not responding to comments either, so ... I just chose this way to respond. Thanks again :)

Using the 'be' in your example is using the subjunctive mood. This was historically used for expressing proposals, intentions, or desires about the future. The verb form used is identical to the bare infinitive:

It is ... vital that our in-flight service be up to par.
It is necessary that he leave at once.
I suggest that he examine the proposal carefully.

The subjunctive is becoming obsolete very rapidly in modern English, especially in Britain, although some people may consider it to be more 'formal' or 'correct'. Modern speakers very much tend towards the plain indicative mood ('is', 'leaves', and 'examines' respectively in the examples above). It may be that those who prepared the practice TOEIC test are not aware of these facts. Such tests may often reflect obsolete or old-fashioned ideas.
The English Subjunctive

Some uses of the subjunctive strike me—an avowed subjunctive user—as pretty much obligatory. As an example, would a Brit say, “I demand that he is released”? Really?

@PaulTanenbaum: I'm "of an age" with Michael here, so we're both perfectly familiar with such use of the subjunctive. He hasn't explicitly said so, but I assume Michael would like to avoid it where possible, same as me. And you're quite right that “I demand that he be [is?] released” is a context where it sounds awkward to avoid the subjunctive, same as it's difficult to avoid outdated "To whom am I speaking?" on the phone. So we just rephrase to "I demand that you release him" and "Who is speaking, please?" No Problemo!

@PaulTanenbaum After the travesty of our democratically elected Prime Minister being pushed out of office, we, his loyal supporters, party members and voters, demand that he is immediately reinstated as Leader of the Conservative Party. 2022 Petition to the UK Parliament

...also if you feel forced to use the subjunctive in contexts like this, I think it's less "starchy" if we include the "subjunctive marker" should - "I demand that he should be released".

Oh, @MichaelHarvey, the horrors! And they call themselves Conservative? Western civilization has now officially come to an end.

This one took me aback! From a guide by Dulwich College on student mental health: Setbacks – and failure – are part of everyday life. All we can ask of your
son is that he tries his hardest (this will, of course, demand that he is honest with himself!).

I thought Boris was okay until i discovered he specifically went to the Ukraine to warn Zelenskyy off engaging in negotiations with Putin. They're all war-mongers, imho.

@PaulTanenbaum - anyone can concoct a Petition to Parliament, and the wording is not really edited very much, as far as I know, so that one belongs to the Joe (or Jane) Public person who wrote it. However, in Hansard I see this The Chancellor is entitled to demand that he is not judged before enough time has elapsed for the new measures overall to work. Report of the Select Committee on Monetary Policy Committee of the Bank of England 1999

@FumbleFingers - I am a card-carrying member of the Labour Party, and I have never held a favourable opinion of Boris Johnson.

@FumbleFingers - yes, I gather we are 'of an age' (I was born 2 months into Elizabeth's reign, so conceived under the old king, if I can put it that way); I instinctively want to use the subjunctive, but have learned to avoid it because of the eye-rolling, blank looks, 'yer whats' and attempts by 12 year olds to correct me
